# Overriding the default org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

We are using the Spring AMQP client to connect to our RabbitMQs and our Spring Config is defined as

```
 <bean id="nativeCF" class="com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory" p:connection-timeout="#{msgProps['messaging.amqp.connection.timeout.millis']?:30000}"
  p:socket-factory-ref="rabbitSslSocketFactory" p:automatic-recovery-enabled="true" p:topologyRecoveryEnabled="false"/>

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="#{msgProps['messaging.amqp.host']}"
  username="#{msgProps['messaging.amqp.username']}" password="#{propertyEncryptor.decrypt(msgProps['messaging.amqp.password'])}"
  port="#{msgProps['messaging.amqp.port']}" requested-heartbeat="#{msgProps['messaging.amqp.heartbeat']?:600}"
  channel-cache-size="#{msgProps['messaging.amqp.channel.cache.size']?:150}" connection-factory="nativeCF"/>
```

- The nativeCF is pointing to basic Java client implementation ConnectionFactory. When I debug my code, I see that the connectionFactory that is autowired is  (org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connectionCachingConnectionFactory )

I want to override the amqp.rabbit.CachingConnectionFactory and autowire it in the config.
Wondering how to proceed.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: No, only spring-amqp

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to do that? If you use the native connection factory directly, you won't get the features that Spring provides, so why use Spring at all?

That said, as long as you declare your autowired variable with the right type, you'll be able to inject the native connection factory.

There is no benefit to using the native client's auto-recovery with Spring; Spring AMQP has (and has always had) its own recovery mechanism that predates the amqp-client recovery.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I edited the post above as the config with <rabbit:connection-factory id was not being displayed. We are using the AMQP CachingConnectionFactory but passing the native client connection factory. Is this also not recommended? Is autorecovery the native RabbitMq client auto recovery?

Comment: It's still not clear what you are trying to do. Yes, it's ok to inject a customized native factory into the CCF, but native `autorecovery` provides no benefit with Spring AMQP; I explained the reasons more fully [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511868/notifying-channel-shutdown-to-classes-implementing-the-org-springframework-amqp/33523403#33523403).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for Spring to autowire `com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory` into a field declared as `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory` (or the other way around) - the two are not type-compatible. You need to declare the field into which you want to autowire with the right type and you should get what you want.

Perhaps you intended to declare the field as `com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory` but you got the Spring type by mistake - check your imports.